# Hausman test VS Mundlak model; the choice between fixed and random effects

Tags: hypothesis-testing, random-effects-model, fixed-effects-model, hausman

I am using panel data and I have to choose between fixed-effects and random-effects models.

I run the Hausman test, the H0 (i.e., the difference in the coefficients from the two models is not systematic) is rejected. Thus, I should use the fixed-effects.

I also run a second test, which is based on the Mundlak model.
So, I run the Mundlak regression (i.e., a random-effects model where I also add the individual means of the time-varying characteristics) and I run an F-test on the extra coefficients (the coefficients of the individual means of the time-varying characteristics).
I cannot reject the null hypothesis. Thus, I should use the random-effect model (although also the fixed-effect is unbiased, the random effect is more efficient).

I am puzzled. I test the same hypothesis in two different ways, obtaining two opposite results.

Comment: What happens when you run the Hausman test on the Mundlak model?

Comment: I have not really been proceeding in that direction. You can look at an evolution of this question at:  [link](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/100168/panel-data-within-group-estimate-individual-fixed-effects-retrieved).

Comment: To answer your question, I have not used the Hausman test to choose between fixed-effects model and the Mundlak model. But, let me ask you a question: would it make sense? The estimates from both the fixed-effects and the Mundlak model would be unbiased (as far as I have understood), and I do not know which one is more efficient (I guess the Mundlak). What would one choose if the Hausman test rejected the H0?